# Typescript interface inherit or provide type

Tags: typescript, type-hinting

I'm trying to write an interface which would inherit a provided type for specific property. This property is dynamically assigned and can contain one of many of other interfaces.

This is my filter.interface.ts:

```
export class Filter {
  [key: string]: {
    isLoading: boolean;
    data;
  };
}
```

And this is my component.ts file:

```
  public filters: Filter = {
    'addressBookTypes': {
      isLoading: false,
      data: <AddressBookType[]>[]
    }
  };
```

How can I write an interface that would pick up the provided type from component? I can't write all combinations of different interfaces since at the moment that would mean about 20 additional interfaces with more on the way. That's why I would prefer to keep one interface, where I overwrite the type of the `data`.

I tried in PhpStorm and if I don't typehint `Filter`, then the code picks up the properties properly, but that is prone to errors or mistyping and that's why I would like to keep the typed interfaces.

Comment: Is [this approach](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4DECWSbBQA8AKgHxwDeAsAFBxwDaA1sAJ4BccaMUOAdgHMAulxr0GcHGgAyEFABMBgrgCMIEJMBT8A3HUlwFKGCi4lGw-RIC+1m3Tow2YYHACCChVGAYAQhrMJC5uALxUdo60CBD8PHAAZngEUGhcuPiERJ7evmgBEEEhFOHiDIq5-oHBrmlUBpLScorKXAkoSGjAADQNDMamXJYNDrSRtEA) using generics what you're looking for?

Comment: Generics looks interesting, but the problem is that I can only set one and not many, as I described in my question.